# Socket send() and recv() not working

Tags: c, sockets

I wrote a simple code to *send()* and *recv()* the data,But I got the error as -1 while I *recv()* the data. The send doesnt give any error.

Server code:

```
struct sockaddr_in name;
char *buf;

int main(int agrc, char** argv) {

int sock, new_sd;   //sock is this socket, new_sd is connection socket
int adrlen, cnt;

name.sin_family=AF_INET;
name.sin_port=htons(6050);

sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

if (sock < 0) {
    printf("\nserver socket failure ");
    printf("\nServer: ");
    exit(1);
}
printf("sockfd=%d\n",sock);
adrlen=(socklen_t)sizeof(name);
if((bind (sock,(struct sockaddr *)&name,adrlen)) < 0)
   printf("\nBind failure");
if(listen(sock, 5) < 0)
   printf("\nlisten error ");
printf("listen done\n");
while(1) {
    if( new_sd =(accept(sock,(struct sockaddr *)&name,(socklen_t*)&adrlen)) < 0) {
        printf("\nserver accept failure ");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("new_sd=%d",new_sd);

    buf = (char *)malloc(14);
    if((recv(new_sd,(void *)buf,14,MSG_WAITALL)) < 0){
       printf("\nError receiving data ");
        exit(1);
    }
}   //end while
return 0;
}
```

Client code:

```
char buf[14];
struct sockaddr_in name;

int main(int agrc, char** argv) {

int sock, new_sd, adrlen, cnt;
name.sin_family=AF_INET;
name.sin_port=htons(6050);

sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

if (sock < 0) {
   printf("\nserver socket failure ");
   printf("\nServer: ");
    exit(1);
}

//stuff for server socket
printf("sock is %d\n",sock);
adrlen=(socklen_t)sizeof(name);


if((connect(sock,(struct sockaddr *)&name,adrlen)) < 0) {
    printf("\nclient connection failure ");
    exit(1);
}

printf("\nSuccessful connection from client 1");

strcpy(buf,"\nclientsend");

if((send(sock,(void *)buf,strlen(buf), 0)) < 0) {
    printf("\nError sending data from client 1 ");
    exit(1);
}
printf("\nExiting normally");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Too much code, too few details about the error. At least print out the error message (using `perror`) so you know what caused recv to fail.

Comment: You forgot to add the address to which you're connecting to in the `struct sockaddr_in` structure.

Comment: the error handling is... well...  `printf("oh no, fatal failure"); no problem, let's continue...`

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of errors that can arise. You should use GetLastError() to find out more about.

Also, I noticed that both in the client and server sample, you didn't completely initialized "sockaddr_in name", for example name.ai_addr is left as it is. In case of TCP (SOCK_STREAM) you need an address to connect to.

Comment: You mean `WSAGetLastError().`

Answer (score -1):

I think this might be your problem: You are sending only 11 bytes from the client, but the server is blocking while waiting for 14 bytes. After the client sends the 11 bytes, it exits causing the socket layer to terminate the connection. The server, however, is still waiting for the extra 3 bytes, when the shutdown sequence is initiated.

To avoid this, on the client side you could send a fixed sized header containing the length of the message. On the server side, first recv the header, extract the length of the message, and then call recv a second time with this length.

Comment: `recv()` unblocks as soon as one or more bytes are received. It does not 'block waiting for [all] 14 bytes'.